# Advanced Filtering in Data Table

Tags: gui-design, web-app, tables, dashboard, filter

**The Problem**

I have a data table, that's on slide-over, fixed to its bottom.
I need do advanced filtering of data.
For example:

```
 1. I want only the drug with exact name "Aspirin"
 2. I want drugs, that contain name "Aspirin" (e. g. "Aspirin for Kids")
 3. I want drugs, both "Lisoprophil" and "Aspirin"
 4. I want drugs, with exact name "Lisoprophil" and all that contain name "Aspirin"
```

Also, I want easily back to defaults (or clear selected) or deselect some of the criteriums.

There is a technical restriction - it should be pop-up or dialog window or something not full-screen.

[image]

So, here I've done some work. But, of course, it doesn't seem perfect solution.

1. I can only add drugs one by one (I should exit pop-up, and then click on filter icon again)
2. Pop-up look and options ("Clear All") varies.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry for grammar mistakes, if any

Comment: So, as example, the result of filtering will be 1. Data row, that has drug "Aspirin". 2. Two different data rows - one has drug "Aspirin", another - "Aspirin for Kids". 3. - 4. The same as 2 - two different data rows, each with its unique drug name.

Comment: Are you having issues in the filter selection or in the filter results?

Comment: @Alvaro I have several issues in filter selection. For example, I don't know how to add several drug names (some can be exact names, and some "contains") at the same time without closing pop-up. I don't know is it ok to show "Clear All" function when he opens filter pop-up and only then.

Comment: Some questions: **1**. When you say exact name "Lisoprophil" and "Aspirin", do you mean both names in the title or only one at least?   **2**. Do you need to differentiate if "contains" refers to one of the specific "exact names". For example in this search query: exact name="Lisoprophil" and "Aspirin" ; contains="for adults" needs to be refered to "Lisoprophil" **or** "Aspirin", or to any of them?

Comment: @Alvaro 1. I mean only the one name in the title. For example that data row will be like: #Patients - 2, Drug Name - "Aspirin". Not "Aspirin","Lisoprophil". Not "Aspirin for kids".

Comment: 2. To any of them, if it's only not the exact drug name :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the case correctly, I suggest:

- Keep the filter edit (add, remove, etc.) in a dialog.
- Differentiate clearly between "exact name " and "might contain".

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's sounds reasonable. But I am looking for the compact solution. I already have slide over with overlay. So, I am doubtful about modal dialog

Answer (score 1):

For the filter menu content, I agree with @Alvaro 's solution.

However, if you find that the current layout is your main problem, I suggest you to use accordion-like menu like the one used on Gmail filter. It is much tidier in my opinion, because the position only expanded from the parent layout (in your case, table header) so it looks more like it only belongs to that column.

[image]